# Why should we use "..." spread operator before using "List.Map()" function in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, list, operators, map-function, spread

I have seen a code like below:

```
...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
    .map((answer) {
  return Answer(
      () => answerQuestion(answer['score']), answer['text'] as String);
}).toList().
```

Inside a `Column widget like below:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Question(
          questions[questionIndex]['questionText'] as String,
        ),
        questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)
            .map((answer) {
              print(questions);
          return Answer(
              () => answerQuestion(answer['score']), answer['text'] as String);
        }).toList()
      ],
    );
  }
```

And the `questions` variable is like following:

```
  final _questions = const [
    {
      'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite color?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Black', 'score': 10},
        {'text': 'Red', 'score': 5},
        {'text': 'Green', 'score': 3},
        {'text': 'White', 'score': 1},
      ],
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'What\'s your favorite animal?',
      'answers': [
        {'text': 'Rabbit', 'score': 3},
        {'text': 'Snake', 'score': 11},
        {'text': 'Elephant', 'score': 5},
        {'text': 'Lion', 'score': 9},
      ],
    },
  ];
```

I can't understand why the `.map()` function doesn't work without using the spread `...` operator in front of this line of the code `...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String, Object>>)` ?

When I try `print(questions)` it gives me a result like this:

```
[{questionText: What's your favorite color?, answers: [{text: Black, score: 10}, {text: Red, score: 5}, {text: Green, score: 3}, {text: White, score: 1}]}, {questionText: What's your favorite animal?, answers: [{text: Rabbit, score: 3}, {text: Snake, score: 11}, {text: Elephant, score: 5}, {text: Lion, score: 9}]}]
```

It seems `questions` is already a list of maps, so why we should use `...` operator in front of that?

Also I found that the code also works if I remove `.toList();` from end of the line.

But if I remove the `...` , it gives me the following error:

```
The element type 'List<Map<String, Object>>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.
```

Answer (score 2):

For example in a column we add an list of widgets.

```
Column:List.generate(7, (index)=> Text('$index')
),
```

The abovr code will generate 7 text widgets in the column.

Now for example you wish to add the elements along with other widgets you add ...

```dart
Column(
 children: [
  Container(),
  SizedBox(height:20),
  //Other widgets
  ...List.generate(4, (index)=>Text('$index')),
 ]
),
```

The above code will add all the elements along with other widgets